# Output file with Data from a SQL query which return an XML prints only the last line

Tags: java, xml, bufferedwriter

I have a SQL query which returns an XML data stored into a string variable. When I write the String to a file it only gives me the last line in the file.

```
 BufferedWriter out=null;
                try {
                    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.xml",true));
                    out.write(XMLout);
                    out.newLine();
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
```

I want to write the whole XML data as it is..

Comment: At first check the data in XMLout object.

Comment: Hmm, did you start a debugger and checked what is in ´XMLout´? What type is it?

Comment: Check XMLout, whether it is bring those data.?

Comment: XMLout is a string variable which has the complete output of the SQL query which is in XML format.

Comment: Did you try reading the output `out.xml` file in a text file reader? Is the data format seen correct?

Comment: yes I tried that same result in both the cases.